# How to set the default page layout from RTL to LTR in  Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, right-to-left

Whenever I open an Excel spreadsheet, it is displayed in a right-to-left layout by default (i.e the right most column is `A` and I need to scroll to the left to reach further columns).

I can change the layout by going to the `Page Layout` menu and disabling the `Sheet Right-to-Left` button.

How can I do it permanently so all spreadsheets are opened in left-to-right mode by default?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

May look at [this](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s5/win004.htm): **UPDATED**

> In Excel 97-2003 there is always a option in Tools > Options on the
>   International tab to change the default sheet direction. But in Excel
>   2007 there is only a option to change the default direction in Office
>   Button > Excel Options ... Advanced if you have installed at least one
>   RightToLeft language.
>   In Excel 2010 they add this option back in
>   File > Options ... Advanced.

In Excel 2010:

[image]

Comment: I took the liberty of quoting the most important parts and adding the screenshot from what you found. If the link ever goes down, that would be bad.. (see: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers))

Comment: The first link is no longer available.

Comment: The screen shot shows how to change it one time, not how to make it permanent. The following answer is accurate (File->Options->Advanced->Display)

Answer (score 7):

In Excel 2010:
Please, follow  this on the menu : File > Options ... Advanced , and scroll down your appearance scroll bar and find **Display** section then you can find Default direction on radio button then check it to what you want

Answer (score 5):

This took me hours to figure out so I'll spare you the time:

Do this one time to change the default direction

1. <kbd>Alt F11</kbd> to open the VBA editor
2. <kbd>Ctrl g</kbd> to open the Immediate window. In the Immediate window type
   `Application.DefaultSheetDirection = xlLTR`
   And press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. <kbd>Alt q</kbd> to close the VBA editor
4. Create a new workbook to test it

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! I only wanted to view it left-to-right permanently. First, I spent half an hour to find the `Sheet Right-to-Left` button, then another half an hour to make it default ...  BTW, the VBA editor doesn't close with Alg-g

Comment: This worked for me on Office 2013. I specifically wanted the default to be RTL, so switching `xlLTR` to `xlRTL` worked

Answer (score 3):

in office 2013, what you need to do is:
go to: file>options>advanced>scroll down to "Display"> choose "left to right" or "right to left" (whatever you need)

Answer (score 3):

In Excel 2016:

File -> Options -> Advanced -> Display Area -> Default Directions
[image]