# direction does to RTL in Excel when I add sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, right-to-left

When I add a new worksheet to my workbook in Excel 2010 (by clicking the button *insert worksheet* next to sheet names), one sheet will be added and the direction goes to RTL from LTR automatically and immediately! So I need to go to *page layout* and correct the direction (to LTR) each time I insert a new worksheet. What can be the problem?

In the Page layout -> sheet options group -> in the left there is button named sheet right to left. When clicking on it, the direction will be changed. That is the Rows list go to the right side of the worksheet screen and by clicking that button once again the Rows list go to another side, this time left.

Comment: Sorry, but this is really unclear. What do you mean by "the direction"? Can you provide an example? You can post a link to a screenshot showing the problem would help.

Comment: You are welcome my friend. In the _Page layout_ -> sheet options group -> in the left there is button named _sheet right to left_. When clicking on it, the direction will be changed. That is the _Rows_ list go to the right side of the worksheet screen and by clicking that button once again the _Rows_ list go to another side, this time left. Could I arrive the issue?

Comment: Do you have a screen shot of this? I don't have that

Comment: Oh, for my version it can be found in `Home - Alignment - "Right-to-left"`. I don't know what would be causing that to change though, sorry. You could use the VBA in [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/378111/how-to-set-the-default-page-layout-from-rtl-to-ltr-in-excel-2010) to make a worksheet_change event, but that seems very cumbersome. I didn't know [tag:right-to-left] tag existed.

Comment: @Raystafarian: Thanks for these: 1- Your editings. 2- Your effort for helping. 3- Your friendly speaking 4- And for your advice. I appreciate you. About your suggestion, I'm an Excel novice without ability of macro, VBA. I was very wondering why when I insert new sheet that direction changes! I'm thinking of malware.